# Remove shown tooltip when new one appear c#

Tags: c#, tooltip

I set the tooltip without timer with the intention to make it permanently displayed.
However, I want it to be removed whenever a new tooltip is created.

The code:

```
        private void ShowTooltip(double d)
    {
        ToolTip tooltip = new ToolTip();
        IWin32Window win = this;
        System.Drawing.Point mousePosition = Cursor.Position;
        tooltip.Show("Text: " + d.ToString(), win, mousePosition);
    }
```

Comment: Then you need to remember all the tool tips and not just make a new one and move on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should Remove existing one:

```
ToolTip.SetToolTip("controller name", null);
```

and this will create new one

```
ToolTip tt = new ToolTip();
tt.SetToolTip(this.pictureBox1, "Your username");
```

Comment: On second thought, can I just moved the position of the old tooltip to the new one (according to the cursor position) ?

Comment: Yes, you also can do that.

Comment: may I know how? Because currently in my case, everytime I trigger the function, the tooltip is not disappeared but creating a new one instead.

Comment: You just apply this solution then see the result it will works for you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating object for ToolTip within the function, just move the toolTip object outside this function i.e. make it a class member.
And use the same instance everytime.
 Use tooltip.RemoveAll() first to remove existing.